# Rails how to return javascript via Ajax call in :update controller action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation, modal-dialog

I am working on a pop up modal box to submit forms. The form is supposed to refresh if there are validation problems, but still inside the modal box. This works for adding a new record, which I believe is calling the :create action, a POST. I want to use the same modal box to edit a record. So far I can get it to open in the modal box, but as soon as there are errors, it redirects to another page instead of staying inside the box. I think that ajax isn't calling the action to return javascript to put the form back inside the modal box. How do I get ajax to return javascript back to the modal box to correct the form?

Example, here is my :create action:

```
def create 
@user = User.new(params[:user])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.js { render :redirect } #this is for modalform     
    format.html { redirect_to(users_url, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
  else
    format.html {render :new}
    format.js # this renders the create.js.erb file to keep the form inside
  end
end
end
```

Here is the javascript that loads the modal box and keeps the form inside until validation is correct:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
$('newuser-link').observe('click', function(event) {
    event.stop();
    Modalbox.show(this.href,
        {title: 'Create',
        width: 500, #up to this point, this opens the form in the modal box
        afterLoad: function() { # this afterload part is supposed to keep the form inside the modal box
            $('new_user').observe('submit', function(event) {
                event.stop();
                this.request();
            })
        }}
    );
   });
 })
```

And here is the .js.erb file that the :create action calls if there are validation errors to keep the form inside the modal box:

```
$('MB_content').update("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form') %>");
Modalbox.resizeToContent();
$('new_users').observe('submit', function(event) {
event.stop();
this.request();
});
```

Being that this works for the :create action, how do I make it work for the :update action when I want to edit a record? Again, the main problem is that when there are validation errors, it redirects outside the modal box.

**UPDATE**:
I discovered that in the part of the javascript that is supposed to keep the modal box open:

```
$('new_user').observe('submit', function(event) {
                event.stop();
                this.request();
```

that the 'new_user' is an id of the form. When using this to edit a record, the id of the form is edit_user_1 or edit_user_32 or whatever user is being edited. So I guess the solution here, which I can't figure out, is how to use a class in the javascript as a selector instead of the id. Because when I manually put in 'edit_user_1' and I'm editing the user with id 1, it works... but obviously not for any other user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ModalBox I ended up using FaceBox (tutorial here):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-build-an-unobtrusive-login-system-in-rails/

which is almost the same, but seemed to be more flexible in terms of adding a class or an id for the selector. Also, when it comes to the dynamic, rails generated id's I used a little jQuery to create a variable that gets the dynamic link and passes it in to the selector:

```
var myid = jQuery('#userform').children().attr('id');
```

Then, where it asks for the id of the form i pass in

```
'#' + myid
```

Anyway, I got this to work by following the tutorial above and was even able to modify it to work with adding a new user and editing one.